Extrapolating standard error of logistic regression in R
I'm trying to extrapolate the mean and standard error range of a logistic regression using the predict function in R, splitting the x axis range up into small pieces and predicting the value at each point. First, predicting just the mean line:
testdata <- data.frame(x = seq(15, 50, by = 5),
                       y = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1))

model <- glm(y ~ x, family = 'binomial', data = testdata)

newdata <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 75, by = 1))
preds <- predict(model, newdata, type = 'response')

preds_df <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 75, by = 1),
                       y = preds)

ggplot(preds_df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(color = 'blue') +
  geom_point(testdata, mapping = aes(x, y))

I get the following output, which seems reasonable.

To add the SE range, I tried using the formula SE = (upper limit – lower limit) / 3.29 for 90% CI from this site. Assuming upper limit = mean + error and lower limit = mean - error, I got error = SE * 3.29/2 and used that to define the bounds of geom_ribbon.
newdata <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 75, by = 1))
preds <- predict(model, newdata, type = 'response', se.fit = TRUE)

preds_df <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 75, by = 1),
                       y = preds$fit,
                   se = preds$se.fit)
preds_df$ul <- preds_df$y + preds_df$se*3.29/2
preds_df$ll <- preds_df$y - preds_df$se*3.29/2

ggplot(preds_df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(color = 'blue') +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = ll, ymax = ul), alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_point(testdata, mapping = aes(x, y))

That produces this output:

My understanding is that for a logistic regression, the SE should be bounded by 0 and 1, like the mean. What is going wrong here?

Strange rule, never seen it before. I also highly doubt that produces valid confidence intervals for non-normal responses, as that ribbon looks suspiciously narrow for such a small sample size.
Anyway, it produces a symmetric confidence interval, which is why it exceeds $(0, 1)$. You want one that is bounded, and so asymmetric except at $p=\frac{1}{2}$.
Try computing the standard error on the linear scale (where a normal approximation may be reasonable) and then transforming to the scale of the outcome:
require("ggplot2")

testdata <- data.frame(x = seq(15, 50, by = 5),
                       y = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1))

model <- glm(y ~ x, family = 'binomial', data = testdata)
newdata <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 75, by = 1))
preds   <- predict(model, newdata, type = 'link', se.fit = TRUE)

inv_logit <- function(eta){
  1 / (1 + exp(-eta))
}

preds_df <- data.frame(x  = seq(0, 75, by = 1),
                       y  = inv_logit(preds$fit), 
                   ll = inv_logit(preds$fit + qnorm(0.05) * preds$se.fit), 
                   ul = inv_logit(preds$fit + qnorm(0.95) * preds$se.fit))

ggplot(preds_df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(color = 'blue') +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = ll, ymax = ul), alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_point(testdata, mapping = aes(x, y))



FWIW instead of defining inv_logit you can just reference model$family$linkinv  which will be whatever inverse link function was used in the model call. Thus you wouldn't need to update anything else if the user decided to use, say, probit, and/or you could reuse the code for other GLM families, such as Poisson
